# merge data inside loop

Tags: php, dom

I try to develop a scrapping price with DimDom (https://github.com/cevin/DiDOM) (like simple HTML Dom)
My problem is to include 2 elements in the same array : title and price

Thank you.

There, my function not finished because I don't find solution.

```
    public function getProductListingPrice($url) {

          $html = $this->getHTML($url); // result of curl
          $element = $this->document->loadHtml($html); // include html content

          $content = $element->first('div.lpTopBox'); // content of the div

          $price = $content->find('span.price'); // price content inside the div
          $title = $content->find('div.prdtBTit'); // title inside the div

          $i = 0;

          foreach($price as $value) {
            $product_price[$i] = $value->text();
            $price_result[] = $product_price[$i];
            $i = $i+1;
          }

          foreach($title as $value) {
            $product_title[$i] = $value->text();
            $title_result[] = $product_title[$i];
            $i = $i+1;
          }

var_dump($title_result);
var_dump($price_result);

          return $result;
    }
```

the result is :

```
array (size=5)
  0 => string 'LG 55EG9A7V TV OLED FULL HD 139 cm (55") - SMART T' (length=50)
  1 => string 'LG 55UJ630V TV LED 4K HDR 138 cm (55") - Smart TV ' (length=50)
  2 => string 'SAMSUNG UE58KU6000 TV LED UHD 147 cm (58") - Smart' (length=50)
  3 => string 'LG 65UJ630V TV LED 4K HDR 164 cm (65") - Smart TV ' (length=50)
  4 => string 'LG 55UJ651V TV LED 4K HDR 139 cm (55") - Smart TV ' (length=50)

array (size=5)
  0 => string '1499€00' (length=9)
  1 => string '689€99' (length=8)
  2 => string '729€99' (length=8)
  3 => string '1141€00' (length=9)
  4 => string '749€99' (length=8)
```

Comment: What is your desired result?  What structure should the merged array have?

Comment: Do you want a single-dimension associative array with `$price_result` as the keys and `$title_result` as the values?  Do you want a two-dimensional indexed array?  Please improve your question as it is Unclear / Too Broad at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of your foreach loop, then instead you can do this:

```
function combineResult($title, $price)
{
    return(array('title' => $title->text(), 'price' => $price->text()));
}
$result = array_map("combineResult", $title, $price);
print_r($result);
```